# Using GeoJSON in Openlayers 4 and Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson

First time trying to draw an Openlayers map with GeoJSON instead of WMS, and not having much luck. My layer is hosted in Geoserver and is named 'sections', in a workspace called 'basic_map'. This is my code so far:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/basic_map/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=basic_map:sections&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    })
    });

 var mapcentre= ol.proj.transform([157.83430,-33.07209],
'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [

      vectorLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: mapcentre,
      zoom: 14
    })
  });
```

The URL link is just copied from the layer preview, which I'm not sure on as some examples use wfs instead.

The developer console also shows an error saying 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8082/geoserver/basic_map/ows?.........'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/cors/index.html

You need to either enable JSONP for GeoServer, or set up cross origin resource sharing.

It's about the same complexity to do both, so I suggest setting up CORS.

Comment: Cheers. There is a jetty-servlet.jar file already included by default in the Geoserver/lib folder, that link you have references a jetty-servletS.jar file to be put into C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\lib. Is there any difference? I also don't have Opengeo suite.

Comment: Hey @Bill, the opengeosuite doco should be similar for GeoServer. Just follow step one in the URL above.

Comment: I'm finding that by adding that <filter> and <filter-mapping> text into my web.xml file, Geoserver won't start after being shutdown, and will start only if I remove the text. I've also changed (in the same web.xml file) ENABLE_JSONP to be true. Any more ideas? Its definitely not an out-of-the-box program!

Comment: Are you running TOMCAT or JETTY? I know it can be fiddly to do these things... but when it's working it will just keep working!

Comment: Its JETTY, and the Geoserver version is 2.11.0. Cheers

Comment: Got it working, I put the steps in a new answer in case someone else wants to see it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alex Leith below for putting me on the right track...the fix was slightly different so I'll give the details:

1. Entered this script into web.xml, found in C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF (sorry the HTML tags are not displaying):

   cross-origin
      org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter 
      
      
      cross-origin
      /*
2. Download and copy jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar into C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib, NOT the path mentioned in the OpenGeo Suite docs. Also I was a bit confused as I already had a .jar file called 'jetty-servlet-', without the 's'. Which is not the same thing.
3. For good measure, I removed the comment markers from this code in the web.xml file, and set it as 'true', eg.

   ENABLE_JSONP
   true
4. For the URL in the openlayers ol.source.Vector/ ol.format.GeoJSON, I just copied the URL from the layer preview. Eg.

   var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
   url: 
   http://localhost:8082/geoserver/basic_map/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=basic_map:sections&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',