# How to import a GeoJSON file from GeoServer using OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have been trying to import the layer that I created in GeoServer. I need to use OpenLayers. This is what I have so far.

```
<!-- language: js -->

<script type="text/javascript">
var serviceUrl = 'https://gis.arlingtonva.us:6443/arcgis/rest/services/public/Bike_Routes/MapServer/';
var layer = '0';
var otherURL = 'Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer';



var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [raster],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-77.0910, 38.8816]),
    zoom: 13.58
  })
});

var bikes = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
 "Bike Routes of Arlington", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ArlingtonBikePath",
 {
         srs: 'EPSG:2283',
         layers: 'Bike_Route',
         styles: '',
         format:'image/png'
 }
);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
var myswitch = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(); 
map.addControl(myswitch); 

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the brief [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to include information about your expected output and where you are having trouble (including the exact text of any error messages).

Comment: Related information: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237237/using-geojson-in-openlayers-4-and-geoserver

Comment: what happens? what doesn't happen? what does the console say? what does the GeoServer log say?

Comment: thanks for looking into it. When I refreshed even the map is gone now. I tried with the  gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237237/… – Mapperz♦ 23 hours ago